# Flutter app not launching on IOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my flutter app on IOS simulator via VS code but app is neither launching nor showing any error in debug console. It just keeps loading but don't show any error

I cleaned and rebuild the app, reset simulator but did not work

Comment: Is doing the same if you create a new project ?

Comment: Is it working using xcode instead of VSC ?

Comment: actually the issue is solved by updating xcode and vscode

Answer (score 0):

When running via vsCode, is the iPhone simulator previously open? Sometimes vscode cannot directly open the simulator on the Mac, if so, check if the target of your application is correct, ideally it should be at least 12 and lastly check if your xcode is up to date, if not update it to be able to run your simulator

Comment: yeah updating vs code and xcode solved the issue 
thanks